# How to update multiple queries in postgresql stored procedure?

Tags: python, django, angular

I want to update table in postgresql using array data as per code.
I am using stored procedures in postgresql.

```
update table_name set number = '123' where type in ('ab','cd')
```

I want to use same above query in stored procedures also but when placing same code in stored procedures getting errors.

Please let me know if anyone has solution for it.